How is the .Xauthority file generated?
I'm creating this question as there does not seem to be much info on certain features/aspects of X11/X Window System readily available online so I would like to gather answers on some questions here.

What exactly does the .Xauthority file do?

How is the .Xauthority file generated?

Can different implementations generate this if needed? For example, xdm, Xvnc, etc.

Is there any recovery in place if this file is not present?


